# Can I have template instantiation side-effects?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

So, lets start with the code that does what I want, but I'd like to teach it a new trick (if it is possible).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A {}; class B {}; class C {}; class D {};

template<typename T> struct traits { };
template<> struct traits<A> { static std::string code() {return "class A";}};
template<> struct traits<B> { static std::string code() {return "class B";}};
template<> struct traits<C> { static std::string code() {return "class C";}};
template<> struct traits<D> { static std::string code() {return "class D";}};

std::string RegisterClass(const std::string & c){
    std::cout << "Registering " << c << '\n';
    return c;
}

template<typename T> void printMe() {
    static std::string t = RegisterClass(traits<T>::code());
    std::cout << "Printing " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
}

int main(void)
{
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<C>(); 
    return 0;
}
```

The output of it is as one might expect -- the "registration" happens only once and only for those types that the template was instantiated with:

```
Registering class B
Printing class B   
Printing class B   
Registering class C
Printing class C
```

What I would like to have is to have only the classes that was used to "register" themselves **before** the first call to the `printMe` function. So the output would look like this:

```
Registering class B
Registering class C
Printing class B   
Printing class B   
Printing class C
```

Superficially, that seems possible. The compiler "knows" which types was used for instantiation . If I were able to store that information in some global or static thingy, then I'd just process it at the beginning of `main()`.

But all my attempts to subvert the compiler into actually doing it have failed so far. Which made me suspect that it is intentional. So 'Can I have template instantiation side-effects? ' he asked, expecting the answer 'no'?

**Edit:** I'm sorry, but I've really failed to clearly express myself in that sentence. In the example above I don't need the registration for `A,B,C and D` -- I need it only for `B and C` and I want the compiler to figure that out by himself somehow.

Comment: Could you afford using a macro/preprocessor ?

Comment: @oglu, obviously, I'd love a pure soution. But If you have something that is industrial-solid standed-the-test-of-time I'd consider that.

Comment: The industrial-solid standed-the-test-of-time solution is to use a REGISTER macro that does the registration, like what most of the test frameworks do. But, there is this guy that has a solution (albeit on the undefined behavior side) which works as you'd like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975672/c-automatic-factory-registration-of-derived-types (check the last answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a static member variable that is instantiated in namespace scope. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct RegisterClass
{
    static RegisterClass instance;
    RegisterClass()
    {
        std::cout << "Registering " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
    }
    static RegisterClass& doRegister() { return instance; }
};
template<typename T>
RegisterClass<T> RegisterClass<T>::instance;

template<typename T> void printMe() {
    RegisterClass<T>::doRegister();
    std::cout << "Printing " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
}
```

[Working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3152664a91f812eb).

The only reason to use a static member function `doRegister` is to avoid warnings from unused variables.

See also [How does the scheme below garantees there'll be just one definition for the objects cin, cout, ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909173/how-does-the-scheme-below-garantees-therell-be-just-one-definition-for-the-obje?lq=1) for some wrinkles related to global objects and order of initialization.

Comment: What if someone accesses `instance` before it's constructed? Typically the point of static locals is to prevent order-of-initialization bugs.

Comment: @MarkB `instance` can be private.

Comment: @MarkB it's still entirely possible to have order-of-initialization bugs in static objects and indeed many people incorrectly abuse static objects in threaded code

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating a helper class whose constructor takes care of registering the classes. Then create an instance of the helper class in external scope.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A {}; class B {}; class C {}; class D {};

template<typename T> struct traits { };
template<> struct traits<A> { static std::string code() {return "class A";}};
template<> struct traits<B> { static std::string code() {return "class B";}};
template<> struct traits<C> { static std::string code() {return "class C";}};
template<> struct traits<D> { static std::string code() {return "class D";}};

template<typename T> 
void registerClass(){
    std::cout << "Registering " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
}

template<typename T> void printMe() {
    std::cout << "Printing " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
}

struct Init
{
   Init();
};

Init::Init()
{
   registerClass<A>();
   registerClass<B>();
   registerClass<C>();
   registerClass<D>();
}

static Init init;

int main(void)
{
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<C>(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't answer the (possibly academic only, but interesting in my opinion) actual question.

Comment: Similar idea as my answer. However this would require adding every type of `T` to the `Init`. On the plus side, it would mean that he could *selectively* have side effects of instantiating each `T` rather than automatically having side effects.

Comment: @RSahu I'm really sorry that I've confused you -- see my edit. (Still, you might notice that the output of your code doesn't correspond to the desired one.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a static member variable and instantiate it.

```
namespace {
    template<typename T>
    class registrar {
    public:
        registrar() {
            std::string t = RegisterClass(traits<T>::code());
        }
    };
}
template <class type> struct traits {
    virtual std::string code() = 0; // override this
private:
    static registrar m_registrar;
};
registrar traits<A>::m_registrar;
```

With this way, any given `T` for `traits<T>` will therefore have a side effect of calling `registrar<T>::registrar()` at runtime start.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but is a bad answer because I'm not sure why the static variable are so weird.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Registrar {
public:
    Registrar();
};

template <typename D>
struct SelfRegistrar {
   static Registrar<D> d_;
    SelfRegistrar(){
        cout << &d_ << endl;
    }
};



//for some reason I don't understand need some reference to d, opening another question...
class A : SelfRegistrar<A> { static void* foo() {return &d_;} };
class B : SelfRegistrar<B> { static void* foo() {return &d_;}};
class C : SelfRegistrar<C> { static void* foo() {return &d_;}};
class D : SelfRegistrar<D> { static void* foo() {return &d_;}};

template<typename T> struct traits { };
template<> struct traits<A> { static std::string code() {return "class A";}};
template<> struct traits<B> { static std::string code() {return "class B";}};
template<> struct traits<C> { static std::string code() {return "class C";}};
template<> struct traits<D> { static std::string code() {return "class D";}};

template <typename D>
Registrar<D> SelfRegistrar<D>::d_{};

std::string RegisterClass(const std::string & c){
    std::cout << "Registering " << c << '\n';
    return c;
}

template<typename T> void printMe() {
    std::cout << "Printing " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
}

template <typename D>
Registrar<D>::Registrar()
{
   std::string c = traits<D>::code();
   std::cout << "Registering " << c << '\n';
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<C>(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's so weird about the static variable?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's more convenient to derive from a base class rather than use embedded or additional helper classes for things like this.  Depending on your needs, this approach can sometimes make things a bit simpler/cleaner and more reusable.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

// Forward declaration for "traits" wrapper class.  If you wanted to, you 
// could to change the self_registering template to not use a wrapper class, 
// default a wrapper but allow other specializations, etc.
template<typename T> struct traits;

template<typename wrappedClass>
struct self_registering {
    self_registering() {};
    virtual ~self_registering() {};
    static bool isRegistered() { return registered; }

private:
    typedef traits<wrappedClass> WrappedClass_;
    static bool doRegistration() {
        std::cout << "Default-registering " << WrappedClass_().code() << '\n';
        return true;
    };
    static const bool registered;
};
template<typename T>
const bool self_registering<T>::registered 
         = self_registering<T>::WrappedClass_().doRegistration();

// our traits wrapper class...
template<typename T> 
struct traits : self_registering<T>   {
    static std::string code() { return typeid(T).name(); };
};

// Well, that's pretty much it. Time to use it:

// a few classes we're going to (maybe) want self-registered...
class A {}; class B {}; class C {}; class D {};
class E {}; class F {}; class G {}; class H {};

// provide custom registration for class H:
template<> struct traits<H> : self_registering<H> { 
    static std::string code() { return "class H"; }

    bool doRegistration() {
        std::cout << "Private-registering " << code() << "\n";
        // do something here like H::register()...
        return true;
    };
};

template<typename T>
void printMe() {
    static bool isRegistered = traits<T>::isRegistered();
    (void)isRegistered; // shut gcc up about unused variable
    std::cout << "Printing " << traits<T>::code() << '\n';
}

int main(void)
{
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<B>(); 
    printMe<C>(); 

    printMe<H>(); 

    return 0;
}
```

With a pure template-based approach for self-registration, one drawback is that if all of your class members functions are `static`, you will at some point need to somehow force registration (as seen in other answers - e.g. RegisterClass(), etc.).

The above code does this by simply referencing the value of a static member variable `registered` in `printMe()`, forcing the compiler to initialize it (which it does by calling `registration()`).  The value is assigned to a `static bool`, so registration should occur only once for each class at startup.

Although the order of registration is not guaranteed across translation units, it should be thread-safe under C++11 (and, if your code doesn't go multi-threaded before static objects are initialized, pre-C++11).  As noted, the drawback is that the `registered` member variable must be referenced *somewhere* in your code.

Compiled/tested using VS2012 as:

```
C:\tmp>cl /nologo /EHsc  /W4 so-misc.cpp
so-misc.cpp

C:\tmp>so-misc
Default-registering class B
Default-registering class C
Private-registering class H
Printing class B
Printing class B
Printing class C
Printing class H
```

and gcc 4.7.2 as:

```
$ gcc -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -Wall -pedantic so-misc.cpp
$ ./a.out | c++filt -t
Default-registering B
Default-registering C
Private-registering class H
Printing B
Printing B
Printing C
Printing class H
```

Obviously, there are other things you could do (further template-ize `self-registering` to make the wrapper class more generic than `traits`, some cleanup, etc.), but this might work for you as a start.

Comment: I think the base doesn't need to be virtual

Comment: @BЈовић: as currently written, probably not, but because it's *intended* to be derived from I just used a virtual destructor as a matter of course.