# What can a nifty counter do that std::call_once can't and vice versa?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I was reading about the Nifty Counter concept and about `std::call_once` and was wondering if they're alternatives where one is more modern (like this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252072/3346771)

Or are there any differences in what those two solutions can achieve.

Comment: I don't think they're similar, would you elaborate more? (where you think they're equal)

Comment: I remove the  c++17 tag because it doesn't seems relevant to question.

Comment: @appleapple e.g. when implementing sort of singletons (like cin or cout or having some other global thing with state) one could theoretically use either. But unfortunately I am not sure what would the limitations be with each choice

Comment: nifty counter solve static initialization and destruction order, call_once doesn't solve initialization (at least directly) and no destruction.